# .net core 3 equivalnet configuration for adding xml serialization

Tags: c#, .net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.0

what should be the equivalent setting for

```
services.AddMvc(options => { 
    options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true; 
})
.AddXmlSerializerFormatters()
.AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();
```

in asp.net core 3.0

Detail of the question can be seen at https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/42085

Comment: Post the question in the question itself *here*, not as a link to another site. What you ask is *definitely* not a CoreFX issue and will probably be migrated and closed very quickly

Comment: The docs already explain how to add XML formatters [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-3.0#add-xml-format-support) `services.AddControllers()
        .AddXmlSerializerFormatters();`

Comment: services.AddControllers(options => options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true).AddXmlSerializerFormatters().AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is found out to be

```
services.AddControllers(options => options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true).AddXmlSerializerFormatters().AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();
```